# Invalid tenant domain Wso2 ESB-AM

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I'm trying to make a simple proxy using one of the store Apis in wso2 AM, but when i send the request this error is shown.

```
{"error" : true, "message" : "Invalid tenant domain."}
```

This is my proxy and I'm using Postman to test it, and i send user and pass as json

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="Login" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable"
  transports="https http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <property expression="json-eval($.user)" name="user"
        scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <property expression="json-eval($.pass)" name="user"
        scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <log level="full">
        <property name="sequence" value="Paso 1 - Login AM"/>
      </log>
      <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
          <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <soapenv:Body>
              <root xmlns="">
                <action>login</action>
                <username>$1</username>
                <password>$2</password>
              </root>
            </soapenv:Body>
          </soapenv:Envelope>
        </format>
        <args>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:user" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:pass" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        </args>
      </payloadFactory>
      <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
      <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
      <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
         <call>
            <endpoint name="Login">
               <address uri="http://187.217.179.35:9765/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag"
                        trace="disable"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>      <property expression="$trp:Set-Cookie" name="setCookieHeader"
        scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <log level="full">
        <property expression="get-property('setCookieHeader')" name="==============Cookie==============="/>
      </log>
      <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag is not a soap web service. It won't work with a soap payload. Try doing a POST request with payload 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin'

Comment: Using these headers and properties I made the transformation to do a request as you say, I mean 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin' that is an application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Done! I have written the two properties with the same name